# Is it possible to hide tabs in the case detail screen

Tags: commcare

I am configuring a case detail that requires a lot of case properties to be displayed across multiple case detail tabs. Some of these tabs are necessary to include for back-end purposes, but aren't actually important to the user.

Is it possible to hide an entire tab to user, in the same way that you can hide individual case list properties by making them 'search only'?

Answer (score 2):

This is not currently possible in CommCare.